# Doing the least amount of GPU work

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, game-engine

Is it possible for an app to "throttle down" from a real time (eg 60fps) graphics app that renders always into simply displaying a "bitmap" (eg a simple bit blit of the 3D world contents instead of a complete re-computation). Then when user input is given (or some application specific conditions occur), it snaps back into real time mode.

With some sort of supervisor code, i imagine that it may be possible to grab the contents of the frame buffer, pause 3d graphics, then just blit over the previously grabbed frame buffer, instead of re rendering an unchanged scene.

This would be in order to save power/fans blowing on weak graphics cards, instead on continuously rendering when not needed.

Is the above a suitable strategy for achieving this - Ie. Is it even possible to "pause" 3D rendering?

Comment: "Is it even possible to "pause" 3D rendering?" Sure: just stop issuing draw commands unless something changes in your scene. Also any decent GUI toolkit is also able to tell you that your OpenGL surface *needs* a redraw (because the OS damaged the window), so also redraw in those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app should react to user input, or other specific event. Only change buffers if data changes. Only update matrices if user moves the camera.

You can draw into a FBO and then blit it to the "normal" frame buffer. This way, only blitting is needed if no change happens.

You can avoid also GPU blitting. Use `glReadPixels` to get the bitmap from that FBO, and use OS API (i.e. with a device context) to blit the bitmap into the window by CPU usage instead of GPU one.

Comment: "*You can avoid also GPU blitting.*" I can't imagine how it would take less power than doing a GPU blit. Doing 2 DMAs requires more power than doing 1. And generally speaking, you can't use native GUI APIs to affect a window owned by OpenGL.

Comment: I don't know OS internals. Mmmm... when you hit "print screen" key does the OS ask GPU for the bitmap or pass to the GPU a stored bitmap? I can imagine both cases and then both GPU & CPU get involved. I do know that CPU energy waste is less than GPU. So if GPU 80% + CPU 20% can be reversed to 20% + 80% we get savings.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thats a good idea about the FBO, will give that a try thanks.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thinking about this a bit more, during normal operation (actively generating a frame each scan), would this scheme not attract an additional copy from said offscreen buffer onto the real screen? Cheers

Comment: Yes FBO is different from "normal" frame buffer. A blit is needed to the real screen. But it's so quick... Btw, what do you mean "additional copy"?